# Retrieve a cookie set in Python serverside

Tags: python, cookies, http-headers

G'day,
I'm following a guide found here: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/Cookie/
which has the code:

```
c = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
c.load(HTTP_COOKIE)
```

to retrieve a cookie previously set (by the server), but my server does not have the HTTP_COOKIE variable, so how else can I do it?
I would prefer to continue using the above guide's method, but if there is something far better I am willing to consider it.
Otherwise, I'm not using any frameworks (just raw .py files) and would like to keep it that way.
Cheers

Comment: Those are code snipeets illustrating the API. HTTP_COOKIE is the *value* of the Cookie header, and you need to get that with whatever method fits your runtime environemnt (like cgi-bin or wsgi).

Comment: Ah yeah, I've got it now with:
import os;
os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE'];

Comment: it'd be a service to the community if you'd answer your own question and accept it :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way discussed in the comments is:

```
import os
def getcookies():
    cookiesDict = {}
    if 'HTTP_COOKIE' in os.environ:
        cookies = os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE']
        cookies = cookies.split('; ')
        for cookie in cookies:
            cookie = cookie.split('=')
            cookiesDict[cookie[0]] = cookie[1]
    return cookiesDict
```

which would then return a dictionary of cookies as `key -> value`

```
cookies = getcookies()
userID = cookies['userID']
```

and obviously you would then add error handling

However there are also other methods, eg., using the [`cookie` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookie.html#Cookie.BaseCookie.load%20cookie%20module)

Comment: `cookie.split('=')` will return a list of n+1 items with n the number of equal signs in cookie. So with `cookie = "example='a value with = sign'"` then `cookies == ["example", "a value with ", " sign"]`. To fix it, use _maxsplit_: `cookie = cookie.split('=', maxsplit=1)`